# Convert Json to flatfile?

Tags: json, vb.net, csv, flat-file

Usually I consume a Json file with

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of DataObject))(jstr)
```

into my dataobjects. Now I am looking for a way to get it into a flat file format (e.g. comma seperated). As a solution I could iterate though my `object.properties` and write it into a `flatfile` but I am looking for a way doing it with an already existing method but cannot find [anything](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm).

Anyone who can help me here?

Comment: CSV isn't "flat file" And if you already have objects, you are looking how to export the objects to CSV, not the original Json data. JSON.NET deals with Json, not CSVs

Comment: I just want to show what I have yet. Going from Json to flatfile directley is prefered over using objects as a intermediate.